# Get operator pop-up current position

Tags: python, scripting, interface, operator

Is there any way to get the current position (x, y) of some active operator pop-up?

[image]

I want to get the correct position even if for some reason I drag this pop-up from it invoke position (Meaning that I can't get the position through original mouse x, y position when this pop-up was invoked)